# RSocket reconnect is not working when the server is restarted in the mid way

Tags: spring-boot, rsocket, spring-boot-rsocket

I am trying to test the reconnection feature of RSocket but it is not working when the sever was brought down in between and restart.

Step 1: Started the client when the server is down

```
16:02:35.351 [main] DEBUG io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelId - -Dio.netty.processId: 55104 (auto-detected)
16:02:35.515 [main] DEBUG io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelId - -Dio.netty.machineId: 10:e7:c6:ff:fe:31:38:c0 (auto-detected)
16:02:35.560 [reactor-tcp-nio-2] DEBUG reactor.netty.resources.DefaultPooledConnectionProvider - [id: 0x7b01559f] Created a new pooled channel, now 1 active connections and 0 inactive connections
16:02:35.569 [reactor-tcp-nio-2] DEBUG reactor.netty.transport.TransportConfig - [id: 0x7b01559f] Initialized pipeline DefaultChannelPipeline{(reactor.right.reactiveBridge = reactor.netty.channel.ChannelOperationsHandler)}
doAfterRetry ===>io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedConnectException: Connection refused: no further information: localhost/127.0.0.1:7999
16:02:36.619 [reactor-tcp-nio-2] DEBUG reactor.netty.resources.DefaultPooledConnectionProvider - [id: 0x8a39ea36] Created a new pooled channel, now 1 active connections and 0 inactive connections
16:02:36.620 [reactor-tcp-nio-2] DEBUG reactor.netty.transport.TransportConfig - [id: 0x8a39ea36] Initialized pipeline DefaultChannelPipeline{(reactor.right.reactiveBridge = reactor.netty.channel.ChannelOperationsHandler)}
doAfterRetry ===>io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedConnectException: Connection refused: no further information: localhost/127.0.0.1:7999
16:02:37.625 [reactor-tcp-nio-2] DEBUG reactor.netty.resources.DefaultPooledConnectionProvider - [id: 0x9754e5dd] Created a new pooled channel, now 1 active connections and 0 inactive connections
16:02:37.625 [reactor-tcp-nio-2] DEBUG reactor.netty.transport.TransportConfig - [id: 0x9754e5dd] Initialized pipeline DefaultChannelPipeline{(reactor.right.reactiveBridge = reactor.netty.channel.ChannelOperationsHandler)}
doAfterRetry ===>io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedConnectException: Connection refused: no further information: localhost/127.0.0.1:7999
```

Step 2: Server Started . Reconnection worked

```
16:08:31.359 [reactor-tcp-nio-2] DEBUG reactor.netty.resources.DefaultPooledConnectionProvider - [id: 0x67b9f3a1] Created a new pooled channel, now 1 active connections and 0 inactive connections
16:08:31.359 [reactor-tcp-nio-2] DEBUG reactor.netty.transport.TransportConfig - [id: 0x67b9f3a1] Initialized pipeline DefaultChannelPipeline{(reactor.right.reactiveBridge = reactor.netty.channel.ChannelOperationsHandler)}
16:08:31.862 [reactor-tcp-nio-2] DEBUG reactor.netty.resources.DefaultPooledConnectionProvider - [id: 0x67b9f3a1, L:/127.0.0.1:57689 - R:localhost/127.0.0.1:7999] Registering pool release on close event for channel
16:08:31.863 [reactor-tcp-nio-2] DEBUG reactor.netty.resources.DefaultPooledConnectionProvider - [id: 0x67b9f3a1, L:/127.0.0.1:57689 - R:localhost/127.0.0.1:7999] Channel connected, now 1 active connections and 0 inactive connections
16:08:31.863 [reactor-tcp-nio-2] DEBUG reactor.netty.resources.DefaultPooledConnectionProvider - [id: 0x67b9f3a1, L:/127.0.0.1:57689 - R:localhost/127.0.0.1:7999] onStateChange(PooledConnection{channel=[id: 0x67b9f3a1, L:/127.0.0.1:57689 - R:localhost/127.0.0.1:7999]}, [connected])
16:08:31.865 [reactor-tcp-nio-2] DEBUG reactor.netty.resources.DefaultPooledConnectionProvider - [id: 0x67b9f3a1, L:/127.0.0.1:57689 - R:localhost/127.0.0.1:7999] onStateChange(ChannelOperations{PooledConnection{channel=[id: 0x67b9f3a1, L:/127.0.0.1:57689 - R:localhost/127.0.0.1:7999]}}, [configured])
16:08:31.891 [reactor-tcp-nio-2] DEBUG io.rsocket.FrameLogger - sending -> 
Frame => Stream ID: 0 Type: SETUP Flags: 0b0 Length: 75
Data:

16:08:31.957 [reactor-tcp-nio-2] DEBUG reactor.netty.channel.FluxReceive - [id: 0x67b9f3a1, L:/127.0.0.1:57689 - R:localhost/127.0.0.1:7999] FluxReceive{pending=0, cancelled=false, inboundDone=false, inboundError=null}: subscribing inbound receiver
16:08:31.969 [reactor-tcp-nio-2] DEBUG io.rsocket.FrameLogger - sending -> 
Frame => Stream ID: 1 Type: REQUEST_STREAM Flags: 0b100000000 Length: 57 InitialRequestN: 9223372036854775807
Metadata:
```

Step 3: Brought down the server

```
16:10:10.993 [reactor-tcp-nio-2] DEBUG reactor.netty.resources.DefaultPooledConnectionProvider - [id: 0x67b9f3a1, L:/127.0.0.1:57689 ! R:localhost/127.0.0.1:7999] Channel closed, now 0 active connections and 0 inactive connections
null
16:10:10.999 [reactor-tcp-nio-2] DEBUG org.springframework.core.codec.CharSequenceEncoder - Writing "ClientName:1607847010998"
16:10:11.008 [reactor-tcp-nio-2] ERROR reactor.core.publisher.Operators - Operator called default onErrorDropped
reactor.core.Exceptions$ErrorCallbackNotImplemented: java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException
Caused by: java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException: null
16:10:11.008 [reactor-tcp-nio-2] ERROR reactor.core.publisher.Operators - Operator called default onErrorDropped
reactor.core.Exceptions$ErrorCallbackNotImplemented: java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException
Caused by: java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException: null
16:10:11.010 [reactor-tcp-nio-2] DEBUG reactor.netty.ReactorNetty - [id: 0x67b9f3a1, L:/127.0.0.1:57689 ! R:localhost/127.0.0.1:7999] Non Removed handler: RSocketLengthCodec, context: ChannelHandlerContext(RSocketLengthCodec, [id: 0x67b9f3a1, L:/127.0.0.1:57689 ! R:localhost/127.0.0.1:7999]), pipeline: DefaultChannelPipeline{(RSocketLengthCodec = io.rsocket.transport.netty.RSocketLengthCodec), (reactor.right.reactiveBridge = reactor.netty.channel.ChannelOperationsHandler)}
16:10:11.010 [reactor-tcp-nio-2] DEBUG reactor.netty.resources.DefaultPooledConnectionProvider - [id: 0x67b9f3a1, L:/127.0.0.1:57689 ! R:localhost/127.0.0.1:7999] onStateChange(ChannelOperations{PooledConnection{channel=[id: 0x67b9f3a1, L:/127.0.0.1:57689 ! R:localhost/127.0.0.1:7999]}}, [disconnecting])
```

RSocket didn't reconnect after the above step. Below is my program. Can someone pls help to review and advice what is wrong with this.

```
        RSocketStrategies strategies = RSocketStrategies.builder()
                .encoders(e -> e.add(new Jackson2JsonEncoder()))
                .decoders(e -> e.add(new Jackson2JsonDecoder()))
                .build();

        RSocketRequester r = RSocketRequester.builder()
                .rsocketConnector(connector ->
                        connector.reconnect(Retry.indefinitely().doAfterRetry(e->  System.out.println("doAfterRetry ===>"+e.failure())))
                ).dataMimeType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .rsocketStrategies(strategies)
                .tcp("localhost", 7999);
```

**Updated on 15/Dec**

Following code sends request after the step 2. After the disconnection, it wasn't able resume the stream. I am sure I must be missing something in my code. Kindly help

```
requester.route("route_name")
                .data("RequestData")
                .retrieveFlux(MyResponse.class)
                .doOnError(ex ->{
                    System.out.println("doOnError"+ex);
                }).doOnCancel(()->{
                    System.out.println("doOnCancel");
                }).doOnComplete(()-> {
                    System.out.println("doOnCancel");
                })
                .subscribe(result -> {
                    System.out.println("===>"+result);
                });
```

Comment: You need to show the code that's making the requests.

Comment: @RossenStoyanchev I have updated my post. Kindly check

Answer (score 0):

The reconnect method has extensive Javadoc. The main purpose of this feature is to establish a single shared connection, no matter how many subscribers there may be at one time:

> When this is enabled, the connect methods of this class return a
> special Mono that maintains a single, shared RSocket

The `Retry` determines how long to keep trying to connect before giving up, but once it stops trying, or once the connection is established and then lost, it won't automatically try to connect again.

> downstream subscribers for individual requests still need their own retry logic
> to determine if or when failed requests should be retried which in turn
> triggers the shared reconnect

So the needs of each individual request determine whether to even try to connect again while the `Retry` given to `reconnect` determines the retry logic for each shared reconnect.

Be sure to review the corresponding code snippets in the Javadoc as well.

Comment: Thanks Rossen. Let me take a look of the java docs corresponding to the methods. Btw, is there any handler event (doOnxxx) in RSocket that notifies when the connection is successful ?

Comment: nothing new because have a similar problem ?